# Running karma e2e on ipad browser

Tags: ipad, karma-runner

How do I run karma e2e on a iPad device (and not simulator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you succesfully running your E2E-tests on your local machine? Karma is configured to run on your public ip, so just make sure you're connected to the same local network, check the ip-adress and open it on your iPad.

Probably something like `http://192.168.x.x:9876/__karma`

Comment: Thanks I have done this .I want to launch browser on device connecting via usb.

Comment: Ah, I see. You don't want to lookup the ip-address but launch it from Karma. Maybe this is what you need? http://xdissent.github.io/karma-ios-launcher/. Note: this uses the new plugin-structure of the unstable Karma@canary.